# Merging two tables in PostgreSQL using `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT IN(..)`

Tags: postgresql, copy

All,

I am trying to bulk insert some data in a table using the COPY TO command and I can't seem to get around the unique key error. Here's my workflow.

Create a dump of the data I want to move to another server

```
COPY (
  SELECT *
  FROM mytable
  WHERE created_at >= '2012-10-01')
    TO 'D:\tmp\file.txt'
```

Create a new "temp" table in the target DB then COPY the data like so.

```
COPY temp FROM 'D:\tmp\file.txt'
```

I now want to move the data from the "temp" table in to the master table in the target DBlike so.

```
 INSERT INTO master SELECT * FROM temp 
                WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM master)
```

This runs fine but nothing gets inserted and no fields are updated. Does anyone have a clue what might be going on here? The schemas for temp and master are identical. Any help on this matter would be great! I am using Postgresql 9.2

Adam

Comment: Maybe temp is a reserved word? Try another name.

Comment: If you manually run: `SELECT * FROM temp WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM master)`, do you get any results? What about `SELECT * FROM temp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master m WHERE m.id = temp.id)`? And what's the output of `SELECT count(*) - count(id) FROM temp;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if there's a `null` value in the `IN` list.

In SQL, the presence of a `null` when making comparisons is always `false` (you need the special `IN NULL` test to get a match). This has the unfortunate consequence of making the *entire* list not match if there's any `null` values returned from `SELECT id FROM master`.

See if there are any rows returned from this query:

```
SELECT id
FROM master
WHERE id is null;
```

If not, then this *isn't* your problem.

If there are values, then the fix is to exclude `null` ids from the list:

```
INSERT INTO master
SELECT *
FROM temp 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM master where id is not null)
```

The other thing to consider is that there are simply no values not already inserted!

Comment: There are many many null values in the table. They insert from my application with no problems and they insert in to the temp table with no problems either. Is there a work around here?

Comment: The id field is the primary key and that will never be null. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: One would assume id to be a primary key, and *thus* not nullable. Maybe the OP wants to show us the table definition?

Comment: @AdamEstrada Then this isn't your problem :(. Could it be that there are simply no values not already inserted!?

Comment: BTW, it's often better to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master WHERE master.id = temp.id)`

Comment: @Craig Ringer I saw that but was a bit confused about the SELECT 1 FROM. What does the 1 represent?

Comment: @AdamEstrada All `EXISTS` does is test whether *anything* results from the query. `SELECT 1 FROM ...` is largely convention for this kind of query, used as a hint to say that the result value doesn't actually matter; you could equally well write `SELECT master.id FROM` if you wanted.